# How to debug PS4 internet browser

Tags: debugging, webkit, playstation4

We noticed our site is not rendered as expected on PS4 browser, is there a way to debug it or get a console?

I know that the PS4 browser is WebKit based so I wonder is there similar debug tools like chrome or safari have?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, I suggest you use a remote console for debugging:

https://jsconsole.com/# - this is a solution for browsers that do not have a debug panel. It can display `console.log()` and JS errors.

Comment: It looks like [JSConsole remote debugging has been deprecated and is no longer supported.](https://github.com/remy/jsconsole/issues/103), and this answer may no no longer be viable.

Answer (score -3):

Sounds tricky but how about using a PS4 UserAgent in Chrome/Firefox?

Comment: what do you mean? how do I do it?

Comment: A useragent will tell the browser how to emulate a different version, a different browser, screen size, etc.,  For example, I've used it to emulate Mobile Safari on Chrome.  I found these two:
Mozilla/5.0 (PlayStation 4 1.000) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko)
Mozilla/5.0 (PlayStation 4 1.52) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko)
Now just add them in your browser of choice's dev tools and it should give you something like what you need.

Comment: hm... the user agent strings are simply headers that signal to the browser which platform you're using. they don't force your browser to behave a certain way. like, by emulating a PS4 user agent string, your browser won't suddenly impose all of the same limited and restrictive capabilities of the PS4 browser

Comment: This does not work. Your only changing the useragent  value. The browser is still Chrome at the end of the day and will now show the issues of a PS4 browser

Comment: Changing the user agent doesn't affect the browser's JavaScript engine.  It won't magically start using the same engine as the PS4.

Answer (score -3):

Have You tried `Ripple Emulator` ?

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc?hl=en

Ripple is a multi-platform mobile environment emulator that is custom-tailored to mobile HTML5 application development and testing.

Comment: This won't work. You need a emulator that what the actual ps4 browser would render