# Vuejs and Bootstrap 4 on PlayStation 4 Internet browser

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, playstation, playstation4

Is there any solution for Vuejs and Bootstrap 4 compatibility with Internet browser on PlayStation 4? When I open my website it just shows our background color and that's it.

So I would like to hear your suggestions. Is there any solution for this? My last solution will be to detect old browsers and show a message that we don't support older browsers.

We use **vue 2.5.16** and **Bootstrap 4**

Comment: Start with some debugging - maybe it's something simple. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37356514/how-to-debug-ps4-internet-browser

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using a server side rendering solution to maximise compatibility.
You can find more information about recommended solution for SSR with vue such as Nuxt.js here https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/ssr.html

Depending on the complexity of your site, using [SSR to pre-render static sites](https://nuxtjs.org/guide#static-generated-pre-rendering-) could be an ideal solution.

I would also recommend adding the snippet you mentioned to inform the user incase there browser is not supported, or better yet forward them to a simpler version that is.