# How to debugging Javascript on browser of PS4?

Tags: javascript, ps4

My website works perfectly on almost browser platform such as browsers for PC, browsers for Smartphone and browsers on android tv but it does not work as expected on PS4 browser and samsung tv browser, the Ajax won't work at all.
There is no debugger on PS4 or SamsungTv so I've used Vorlonjs and only got this message in console:

```
jquery.deferred exception: can't find variable:
```

I've double checked but didn't get luck, it does work on other platforms but PS4 and Samsung TV.
Can anybody give me some advise and is there anyway to debugging deeper on those platforms?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to debug PS4 internet browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37356514/how-to-debug-ps4-internet-browser)

Comment: I know that but the solution is no longer working, I've found an alternative solution named Vorlon but i would love to know is there a better solution?

Comment: You might want to check this article: https://github.com/remy/jsconsole/issues/103

Comment: Thank you, I will note this in the noted dupe and have retracted my close vote.

Answer (score -1):

You can try adding your own error catching functionality and print errors on screen, or send them to your server:

```
window.onerror = function (msg, url, lineNo, columnNo, error) {
  // ... handle error ...

  return false;
}
```